# FOSS Newsletter application

Tags: linux, open-source

What newsletter application would you recommend? It should handle large lists of recipients, GUI for making the letter and you should be able to make templates for easy re-use.

It should be geared toward people with html/css skills but without programming skills.

It should run on linux, be free and open source.

edit:

All I've seen so far is based on either php/asp and accessible from a browser, that's the kind of thing I'm looking for.

Good point!

Comment: There are already two questions which have discussed this: http://superuser.com/questions/35743/desktop-mailing-list-management and http://superuser.com/questions/13683/mailing-list-with-subscribe-unsubscribe-features

Answer (score 1):

There's one I know of:

**[inwise Desktop](http://www.inwise.com/inwise-Desktop-Newsletter-Software.aspx#Features)**:
 A complete desktop solution including newsletter subscription and unsubscription facilities. **Free** if you don't plan to have more than **500 subscribers** at any time. They also have an online service which may interest you. I used their software in the past to setup a corporate mailing list for the companies internal mail groups. Worked like a charm and it is my guess they are still using it today.

> - Easy Deployment, simple and quick installation.
> - 3 HTML free templates included to easily create professional & branded
>     messages, send company newsletters and
>     announcements.
> - Excel import and exportyour groups of recipients.
> - Automatic handling of duplicate email addresses – if your mailing list
>     includes duplicate email addresses,
>     the software will not send the same
>     message twice.
> - Bounces Automatically handles bounces.
> - Unsubscribe – Automatically handles unsubscribe requests.
> - A simple, friendly user interfacethat allows you to create
>     professional messages, send
>     newsletters and email messages in few
>     minutes.
> - Personalization features to send messages addressed individually to
>     friends, clients and customers.
> - Graphical real time tracking report - to provide you with details on the reactions your email generates, such
>     as open and clickthrough rates, in
>     order to help you learn about the
>     effectiveness of your campaign. inwise
>     Desktop Real Time Reporting updates
>     your campaign reports immediately.
> - "Can-Spam" compatible - our delivery mechanism follows the "Can-Spam"
>     standards and handles any bounces and
>     unsubscribe requests and automatically
>     updates your data bases.

Answer (score 1):

> [Scribus](http://scribus.net) is an Open Source program that brings professional page layout to Linux/UNIX, Mac OS X, OS/2 Warp 4/eComStation and Windows desktops with a combination of press-ready output and new approaches to page design.
>
> Underneath a modern and user-friendly interface, Scribus supports professional publishing features, such as color separations, CMYK and Spot Color support, ICC color management, and versatile PDF creation.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a desktop application!? That almost seems to 1990s, but then again I'm really not into newsletters. If you can get past my smart-ass response, I think MailChimp (http://www.mailchimp.com) is a very good newsletter alternative. They have free and paid subscriptions and it's super easy to use.

Answer (score -1):

If you'll chose inwise's solution for email marketing, their's email marketing service (Saas - software as a service) is better than the desktop I think.
You can create a free account - www.inwise.com